# ListView adapter and focus state

Tags: android, background, focus

I have some ListView. This is code of item view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/list_drawable_settings"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/section"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        <com.vk.messenger.views.TextViewMyriadPro android:id="@+id/word"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
     </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <com.vk.messenger.views.RoundedConersImageView android:id="@+id/userpic"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="9dip" android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
                   android:layout_marginTop="6dip" android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                   android:layout_height="40dip"
                   android:layout_width="40dip"/>
        <com.vk.messenger.views.TextViewMyriadPro android:id="@+id/name"
                  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userpic"
                  android:textColor="@color/friends_text_color"
                  android:textSize="15dip"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/online"
                   android:visibility="invisible"
                   android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:src="@drawable/online_list"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When element of listview focused, background of main layer changes. How to change text color of textview elements WHEN main element focused?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english(

Answer (score 0):

My idea of doing this is to create a custom array adapter with an integer variable representing the color of your textview elements. In the `getView` method of your custom adapter you will set the color of your textViews. Something like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends
    BaseAdapter {

private String[] data; //Your data
private Context context;
    private int textViewColor = Color.BLACK; //The color of your textViews with a default value

public CustomAdapter(Context _context, String[] _data) {
    context = _context;
    data = _data;
}

    public void setColor(int _color) {
        textViewColor = color;
    }

    //Use a viewholder if you havent already for more efficient listView.
    static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView textView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = inView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_list_view_item_layout, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_textViewId);
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

          viewHolder.textview.setTextColor(textViewColor); //Set the color of your textViews
          //Do anything else you are supposed to...
   }

  ....
}
```

Then set a `OnFocusChangeListener` on your listView. In there, set the new color of your textViews. Something like this:

```
listView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
                    adapter.setColor(Color.White); //set the new color of your textViews components
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Call this to update the listview

                }
            });
```

If you want to change only the color of the textView of the selected item in the listView you need to add the onFocusChangedListener to the listViewItem on the `getView()` method in the adapter. Something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = inView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_list_view_item_layout, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_textViewId);
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }


          //set the onFocusChangedListener in the View item of the listView
          v.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewbyId(R.id.your_textViewId);
                if(hasFocus) {
                      textview.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
                else {
                      textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }

            }
        });

          //Do anything else you are supposed to...
   }
```

Comment: I think that this code change all textView colors? But I need change textview only in focused listitem.

Comment: @Anton I edited my answer, to do what you need. See the last block of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is real simple with [stateful colors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html):

Create "color list" file. For example `res/color/font_color_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <item
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

Then in your layout: `<TextView android:textColor="@color/font_color_selector" ... />`