# How Do I Determine If ListView Row is Focused?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, focus, adapter

I'm a noob to android development and I am trying to make a listview that has a VideoView in each row.  I want the VideoView to begin playing once the row comes into focus and stop playing when the row is out of focus, similar to how instagram does it. I have set the OnFocusChangeListener on my View within my getView method in my Adapter Class, as suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328327/listview-adapter-and-focus-state). However, the OnFocusChange method never seems to get called.  How can I determine which ListView row is in focus? Any help resolving this is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.allmedialist_row, null);

        holder.clubname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.clubname); // title
        holder.dates = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        holder.vidimg=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        holder.clubimg =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.clubimg); // thumb image
        holder.playimg =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.playimg); // thumb image
        holder.username = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.username); // artist name
        holder.video_screen = (VideoView)vi.findViewById(R.id.VideoView1); // artist name
        holder.header = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.header);
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.video_screen.setTag(position);
        holder.username.setTag(position);    

        vi.setTag(holder);
   //   vi.setFocusable(true);
   //   vi.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);  

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    song = data.get(position);

    vi.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {

                Log.e("HAS FOCUS", "true");

            }else {

                Log.e("NO FOCUS", "true");

            }

        }
    });
    vi.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 


   return vi;
}
```

Comment: u mean in the log only NO FOCUS is shown not HAS FOCUS?

Comment: @MohammedAli neither log message is shown.

Comment: means OnFocusChangeListener() is not called?

Comment: @MohammedAli correct OnFocusChangeListener() is not called.

Comment: You added return vi just now... did it work?

Comment: i would set a scroll listener on the list view and using firstVisibleItem and visibleItemCount calculate in average the position in the middle, than play the video inside the view in that position.

Comment: it didn't work.. deleting my answer..

Comment: @DollaBill OnFocusChange is not being called because when you scroll a listview then it does not mean that a row get a focus. TheRedFox's approach is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you. Basically a setOnScrollListener with onScroll method which can access visible rows of listview, and find the position of row with getTag(Before that you need to use setTag like you did with username TextView).

Again as TheRedFox has mentioned you need to find average of positions. and may find the middle row from visible rows of listview.

```
        mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            int sumOfPosition = 0;

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i <= mListView
                    .getLastVisiblePosition(); i++) {

                Log.e(TAG, "i = " + i);
                Log.e(TAG, "mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() = "
                        + mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

                View childView = mListView.getChildAt(i
                        - mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

                if (childView != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "childView != null");
                    TextView mTextView = (TextView) childView
                            .findViewById(R.id.username);

                    Log.e(TAG, "tag position = " + mTextView.getTag());
                    sumOfPosition = sumOfPosition
                            + Integer.parseInt(mTextView.getTag()
                                    .toString());
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "childView = null");
                }
            }
            if (visibleItemCount != 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Possible focused row position = "
                        + (int) (sumOfPosition / visibleItemCount));
            }
        }
    });
```